# How improve jquery autocomplete plugin

Tags: jquery, plugins, autocomplete

I'm using jquery autocomplete plugin and i want to improve it.

I have in my array for example the word "Format".

The plugin works well if I type :

> "For..."

.

I want to also write

> "for..."
>
> "ormat"

or better

> "tamrof"

How can i do that ?

Comment: Anagrams? You want it to work on anagrams...? For `for..`/`ormat` problem, use a case-insensitive regex that looks at the whole string, not just the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery UI Autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) is already case insensitive (`for` will match `Format`) and matches anywhere (`rma` will match `Format`). If you use a different one you will have to state which.

To search for the term backwards... you could check if there are no matches, [reverse the input string](http://eddmann.com/posts/ten-ways-to-reverse-a-string-in-javascript/) and search again. You can do that with a [response callback](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-response) in jQuery UI Autocomplete. But ***why*** would you need to match backwards terms?